# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined Jest react testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ts-jest

I'm new to react and testing so maybe I'm misunderstanding the docs but I have a function that defines a **const variable** which is just an array of objects that has a property 'X', we'll call it. I filter this array and take the first object and look for X.

I then import it into my jest test file but it fails when I run the test, saying that ***Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined]***.

I'm unsure as to why, as when I actually run the app it works so I'm assuming some kind of variable mocking needs to happen?

Below is my code. I've stripped out the non important parts. If anyone can guide me in the right direction please.

main.jsx

```
 export default function main({
    name, value, options, onChange, onBlur, inputRef, error, complete
}) {
  const data = options.filter(name => name.uuid === value)[0].X.slice(8);

   return ( blah blah blah, this works when I actually render it )
```

test.jsx

```
import main from './main';

test('Renders', () => {

const options = [
  { 
    uuid: 'foo', 
    X: ['a', 'b'] 
  }
]

  const { getByText } = render(
    <main
      name="test"
      value=""
      options={options}
      onChange={() => {}}
      onBlur={() => {}}
    />
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you pass props `value` is "" so `options.filter(name => name.uuid === value)[0]` is undefined. You can update `value` to fix

```
value="foo"
```

Comment: thank you!!! I spent hours on this not being able to see why. I guess it was just one those things where you needed a second pair of eyes on it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an empty value so the filter method throws an empty array and when u try to access its first element you get undefined.

That's why the error `Cannot read property 'X' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a filtered array of elements which have passed the condition specified in the callback.

Either change your filter condition or pass in `foo` as value:

```
<main
      name="test"
      value="foo"
      options={options}
      onChange={() => {}}
      onBlur={() => {}}
/>
```

Otherwise, you are checking for the 0th element of an empty array, which is undefined.